# How to plot several curves in MATLAB using handles

Tags: matlab, real-time, handle, lineseries

I am plotting data in MATLAB in real time. I want to use a handle. My problem is I do not know how to plot more than one Y-Data Curve.

I found the following code
It shows how to plot one set of YData. Has anybody got an idea to transform the code into two or more Y-Datasets, e.g. sind(x) as an additional curve in the plot?

```
x = 1:1000;
y = cosd(x);

xi = x(1);
yi = y(1);
h = plot(xi, yi, 'YDataSource', 'yi', 'XDataSource', 'xi');

for k = 2:1000...
xi = x(1:k);
yi = y(1:k);
refreshdata(h, 'caller');
drawnow;
end;
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code works for me, if you really want to use handles

```
x = 1:1000;
y = cosd(x);
y2 = sind(x);

xi = x(1);
yi = y(1);
yi2 = y2(1);
figure(1); clf;
h = plot(xi, yi, 'YDataSource', 'yi', 'XDataSource', 'xi');
hold on;
h2 = plot(xi, yi2, 'YDataSource', 'yi2', 'XDataSource', 'xi');

for k = 200:1000
    xi = x(1:k);
    yi = y(1:k);
    yi2 = y2(1:k);
    refreshdata(h);
    refreshdata(h2);
    drawnow;
end;
```

You do need a `hold on`.

Also, instead of `refreshdata` you can use `set` as Andrey suggested:

```
set(h,'Xdata',xi,'YData',yi);
set(h2,'Xdata',xi,'YData',yi2);
```

Comment: Thanks very much! For me your example did it! The real time plot works now showing multiple curves. Great Answer!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, never use `refreshdata`. Use the direct `set` method instead.

```
        set(h,'Xdata',xi,'YData',yi);
```

Secondly, you should do two plots

```
      h1 = plot(xi, yi);
      h2 = plot(xi, yi);
```

And update each one accordingly.

Comment: Thanks very much so far Andrey. If I do two plots, doesn' t that mean there will be two figures? Am a Matlab Beginner, so pardon me if this idea is stupid.

Comment: Andrey, why should you not use `refreshdata`?

Comment: @angainor, a very good question. I just wrote it as question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe looking for the [`hold` command](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)?

```
plot(1 : 10, (1 : 10).^2, 'r')
hold on
plot(1 : 10, (1 : 10).^3)
```

EDIT:

You can use `hold` in combination with `set` to update the plot (see also [Andrey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817452/andrey) answer):

```
h1 = plot(1 : 10, (1 : 10).^2, 'r');
hold on;
h2 = plot(1 : 10, (1 : 10).^3);
set(h1, 'XData', 1 : 2 : 20);
set(h2, 'YData', 0.1 * (1 : 20).^3);
```

The axes will update automatically.

Comment: Hey Florian. I read that when doing real time plots it is supposed to be more efficient to use handles. Apart from that, hold on freezes my axes (I believe at last so) which I do not desire. The implementation works well with handles apart from the fact that I am not able to plot multiple lines.

Comment: @user1677716 `hold on` does not freeze your axes.

Comment: @user1677716: You can use `hold` together with handles, see my edit. Also, as angainor pointed out, the axes will still auto-update.

Comment: If you like hold, "hold on" will give you multiple curves in the same color. Use "hold all" to get different colored curves (as if you had plotted all the curves with one plot command).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about displaying the same colour for all curves, simply concatenate the x data into a single vector separated by NaN between the curve components (do a similar thing for the y data). Then the "plot" command can take in these larger x and y vectors and will display everything at once. You may get around the colour issue by doing something similar with the colordata array.