# Why aren't the points being displayed?

Tags: matlab, debugging

Why aren't the points being displayed?
I am trying to plot four different interpolated points with different symbols on top of the plot. I have to create a legend that has the shapes corresponding to the points.

```
A=[1.52 -.7;.56 .4]
l=eig(A);
L=max(l);
Xo=[1;0];

for k = 1:50
Xk=A*Xo;
Xo=Xk;
if k == 1
plot(Xo,Xk,'mo');
elseif k == 2
    plot(Xo,Xk,'mx');
elseif k == 3
    plot(Xo,Xk,'m+');
elseif k == 4
    plot(Xo,Xk,'m*');
elseif k == 5
    plot(Xo,Xk,'ms');
else
    plot(Xo,Xk);
end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `hold on`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to plot here though. I believe `hold on` will fix your problem but I recommend you take a step back. Every iteration you are calculating Xk, ou then set xo equal to this value and plot the two values (which are now the same). This will always be a straight line.

Answer (score 2):

By default, every time you call `plot` Matlab will clear the figure and "start again".

If you want to plot two things on top of each other, you can use either

```
hold on
```

or

```
hold all
```

These are subtly different. With `hold on`, you leave "everything unchanged". The next plot will use the same color as the last one, etc. With `hold all`, your next plot will be a different color (but it will not erase the previous plot).

Thus you can change your code as follows:

```
A=[1.52 -.7;.56 .4]
l=eig(A);
L=max(l);
Xo=[1;0];

for k = 1:50
Xk=A*Xo;
Xo=Xk;
if k == 1
    plot(Xo,Xk,'mo');
elseif k == 2
    plot(Xo,Xk,'mx');
elseif k == 3
    plot(Xo,Xk,'m+');
elseif k == 4
    plot(Xo,Xk,'m*');
elseif k == 5
    plot(Xo,Xk,'ms');
else
    plot(Xo,Xk);
end

hold all; % <<<<< this is the extra line

end
```

This is really very inefficient code though - but the best way to fix that might want to be the subject of another question.

Comment: See this question on how to update plots in a loop efficiently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab

Comment: @Raab70 - interesting link. I think that since OP wants to plot a few points with different markers (and corresponding legends) the methods in your link don't apply in this case - but good for general reference.

Comment: .... and after 6 years I found out that there was a significant difference between `hold on` and `hold all` =P I guess I've always set the colors manually.