# How should I update the data of a plot in Matlab? part - 2

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is a continuation from the question already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab). I used the method that @Andrey suggested. But there seems to be a limitation. the `set(handle, 'XData', x)` command seems to work as long as x is a vector. what if x is a matrix?

Let me explain with an example.
Say we want to draw 3 rectangles whose vertices are given by the matrices `x_vals` (5,3 matrix) and `y_vals` (5,3 matrix). The command that will be used to plot is simply `plot(x,y)`.

Now, we want to update the above plot. This time we want to draw 4 rectangles. whose vertices are present in the matrices `x_new`(5,4 matrix) and `y_new` (5,4 matrix) that we obtain after some calculations. Now using the command `set(handle, 'XData', x, 'YData', y)` after updating `x` and `y` with new values results in an error that states

`Error using set
Value must be a column or row vector`

Any way to solve this problem?

```
function [] = visualizeXYZ_struct_v3(super_struct, start_frame, end_frame)

% create first instance
no_objs = length(super_struct(1).result);
x = zeros(1,3000);
y = zeros(1,3000);

box_x = zeros(5, no_objs);
box_y = zeros(5, no_objs);

fp = 1;

% cascade values across structures in a frame so it can be plot at once;
for i = 1:1:no_objs

    XYZ = super_struct(1).result(i).point_xyz;
    [r,~] = size(XYZ);
    x(fp:fp+r-1) = XYZ(:,1);
    y(fp:fp+r-1) = XYZ(:,2);
    % z(fp:fp+r-1) = xyz):,3);
    fp = fp + r;

    c = super_struct(1).result(i).box;
    box_x(:,i) = c(:,1);
    box_y(:,i) = c(:,2);

end
x(fp:end)   = [];
y(fp:end)   = [];

fig = figure('position', [50 50 1280 720]);
hScatter = scatter(x,y,1);
hold all
hPlot = plot(box_x,box_y,'r');
axis([-10000, 10000, -10000, 10000])
xlabel('X axis');
ylabel('Y axis');
hold off
grid off
title('Filtered Frame');


tic
for num = start_frame:1:end_frame
    no_objs = length(super_struct(num).result);
    x = zeros(1,3000);
    y = zeros(1,3000);

    box_x = zeros(5, no_objs);
    box_y = zeros(5, no_objs);
    fp = 1;

    % cascade values accross structures in a frame so it can be plot at once;
    for i = 1:1:no_objs

        XYZ = super_struct(num).result(i).point_xyz;
        [r,~] = size(XYZ);
        x(fp:fp+r-1) = XYZ(:,1);
        y(fp:fp+r-1) = XYZ(:,2);
        fp = fp + r;

        c = super_struct(num).result(i).box;
        box_x(:,i) = c(:,1);
        box_y(:,i) = c(:,2);

    end

    x(fp:end)   = [];
    y(fp:end)   = [];

    set(hScatter, 'XData', x, 'YData', y);
    set(hPlot, 'XData', box_x, 'YData', box_y); % This is where the error occurs

end

toc

end
```

Comment: @Andrey Just wanted to know if the question was clear and made sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line on the plot has its own `XData` and `YData` properties, and each can be set to a vector individually.  See [the reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html?searchHighlight=xdata%20property).  I am not at a Matlab console right now, but as I recall...

```
kidnum = 1
h_axis = gca       % current axis - lines are children of the axis
kids = get(h_axis,'Children')
for kid = kids
    kid_type = get(kid,'type')
    if kid_type == 'line'
        set(kid,'XData',x_new(:,kidnum))
        set(kid,'YData',y_new(:,kidnum))
        kidnum = kidnum+1
    end
end
```

Hope that helps!  See also the [overall reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/organization-of-graphics-objects.html) to graphics objects and properties.

To add a series, say

```
hold on   % so each "plot" won't touch the lines that are already there
plot(x_new(:,end), y_new(:,end))   % or whatever parameters you want to plot
```

After that, the new series will be a child of `h_axis` and can be modified.

Comment: my first look at the code tells me that you are modifying existing lines. But for me, the dimension of `x_new` and `y_new` will change every time I run your for loop. In other words, the number of lines that I want to draw are not constant. How do I add newlines or remove existing lines from the plot? correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @bvk - edited the answer to indicate.  Again, doing this from memory, so YMMV :)