# How to update an image position using set(h,...) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, arguments, handle

I have a picture that is plotted inside a figure in Matlab:

```
pic=imread('mypic.bmp');
figure(1)
h=image([1 1.2],fliplr([1 1.2],pic)
```

Now I want to move this figure to other locations inside the figure, with the method that is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab):

```
for i=2:3
    indices=[i i+.2];
    set(h,'?1',indices,'?2',fliplr(indices))
end
```

What do I have to fill in instead of `?1` and `?2`? In the referred question, where the `plot` command is considered, they use `XData` and `YData`.

Comment: Did you try `XData` and `YData`?

Comment: No because I thought it should be something different. But it works!
@Suever - Can you answer the question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image objects (whether created with `imshow`, `imagesc`, or `image`) *also* have [`XData` and `YData` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html).

```
xdata = get(h, 'XData');
ydata = get(h, 'YData');
```

They specify the x and y range of the image data. You can alter them the same way as you would for `plot` objects.

```
for k = 2:3
    indices = [k, k+0.2];
    set(h, 'XData', indices, 'YData', fliplr(indices));

    % Be sure to make it so the axes can display it
    set(gca, 'XLim', indices, 'Ylim', indices);
end
```