# MATLAB imshow? How to free memory but show the image?

Tags: image, matlab

I read a video, but I want to show frame one by one, but when I show the frame, I found my memory leak out, and my program get slow, it shows that imshow() will  not free the memory, so can I free the memory after showing the image, but the image never goes out, I can show the image frame by frame as well?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: You might want to read [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you are doing something like

```
hold on
for ii=1:frames
    imshow(frame)
    drawnow
end
```

as most memory problems are due to this structure. If you `hold on` and never clear the figure, you will draw on top of whatever is there, but it will never get deleted. I suggest you remove the `hold on` if you are just drawing a single thing inside the loop, and if you are drawing more than one thing inside and you *need* the `hold on`, then add [`cla`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html?refresh=true) (clear axes) or [`clf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html) after the `drawnow`, or in the begging of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I just clf before next imshow function, and problem is fixed!

Comment: @JinghengLuo consider accepting the asnwer as valid if it helped you! (small tick nest to the upp/down arrows)